# MobiLink: What is the correct approach of presetting values inside database for remote user

Tags: sybase, sybase-sql-anywhere, sap, mobilink, sybase-central

When creating a remote database from inside Sybase Central I'm looking for a way to preset some values based on e.g. subscription user.

Application is using some kind of configuration table storing e.g. a base value for new id (it's historical handled inside application). To prevent collisions it's needed to set these values inside configurations table during creation of remote database.

One approach would be to run custom SQL after everything is done. But I'm wondering whether there is a way to include it into synchronisation profile of Sybase Central